# Find and Replace text in a single table using mysql query if a field is equal to x

Tags: php, mysql

To find and replace a text in a single table the sql command is:

```
UPDATE `table_name`
   SET `field_name` = replace(same_field_name, 'unwanted_text', 'wanted_text')
```

I need to find and replace text in `field_name` if the filed 'language' is equal to "en-GB"

this sql doesn't work:

```
UPDATE `field_name` WHERE `field_name`.`language` = "it-IT"
SET `field_name` = replace(same_field_name, 'unwanted_text', 'wanted_text')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query should be like this

```
UPDATE Table_name SET field_name = replace(field_name, 'unwanted_text', 'wanted_text')
     WHERE language = "it-IT"
```